# My drag & drop is not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile

As you can see on the upper image, there are align options "to RightOf=button", "below=button" when you drag something, but when I drag something nothing like that is shown. Can anyone help me fix that?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_witaj_uzytkowniku"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/witaj_uzytkowniku" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @JakirHossain so how do I change that ?

Comment: @JakirHossain do you mean content_main.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I prefer to use ConstraintLayout as the root. I believe it is much easier to use with the drag and drop tool.

When using it make sure that [all objects are connected to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF6E0.png)(or the parent) at least once vertically and once horizontally.
How this looks in the code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can also adjust the distances using the [side panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vPv9.png).

To use the layout you just need to type Constraint layout in the Pallete and drag it (if it is not installed, there will be a download)

Answer (score 0):

Set position of your `textview` then try to add another view by dragging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_witaj_uzytkowniku"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop ="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/witaj_uzytkowniku" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of Relativelayout, you should use the [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout). 
And if you continue with Relativelayout then go to file invalidate and restart your Android studio if this is cache related issue then resolved it.

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: By default the UI help window not come in android studio, it is possible only if any addon/plugging install as per my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Use Coordinator Layout to work. RelativeLayout is more of coding layout..

Comment: create a new project and try or update use ConstraintLayout and if even dont update ConstraintLayout version the latest version is 1.1.3